# Why is array_udiff returning common elements?

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

How should array_udiff actually be used? The results fromt eh following test seem a bit weird compared to the logical expected result.

```
$a1 = array('red');
$a2 = array('red', 'blue');

$diff = array_udiff($a1, $a2,
        function($a, $b) {
            if($a === $b) {
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                return -1;
            }
        });

var_dump($diff);
```

The above outputs :

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'red' (length=3)
```

**Why?**

To better show the problem here is the output of the internal array_diff :

```
$internalDiff = array_diff($a1, $a2);

var_dump($internalDiff);
```

Output :

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

**What???!!! ( :) )** . The second output seems logic, but why does array_udiff does not give the same output?

Comment: You should probably `return 1;` in your function callback, as shown in the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.array-udiff.php).

Comment: @A.L Yes I saw that by using 1 instead of -1 it returns the correct value. But why? :) . I mean in either case, red should never be returned, because both have that value.

Comment: I don't know, the PHP documentation doesn't explain it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct, if you take a look at the manual you see why and also how it works: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php

And a quote from there:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Comment: I still don't get where the logic is and how it should be used. Check my question edits.

Comment: @GeoC. Is you question now about `array_diff()` or about `array_udiff()` ?

Comment: The question is why isn't array_udiff giving the proper output? They should work the same, except that you must provide the comparison function. As you can see, in my anonymous function if($a === $b) then the elements are the same. But surprinsingly , the output is exactly the common element :)

Comment: Write an example of array_udiff that returns an empty array. Comparing the same arrays I was in my example. Because I want to get the values that are present in the first array and not in the second (at least that's what array_diff returns, same return that array_udiff should have but for some reason it doesnt).

Comment: @GeoC. You just have to change your conditions to this: `if($a !== $b) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
   
   
                return 0;
            }`

Comment: Yes, I saw that if you change from -1 to 1 the output is correct. But why? :) . Something is still wrong there. Try -1 and you'll see red again :)

Answer (score 0):

One year later... But with array_udiff, I think PHP will think that if a > b and b > c, a != c, so it will act as if a != c, even if a & c are equals.
Using array_udiff, you really have to listen to PHP documentation, and return -1 and 1, depending on the case, not just -1 or 1 when it's not egal, otherwise it won't work as you expect it to work.

I found this post because I has the same issue, and same as Geo C, I didn't understand why my array_udiff was returning common element. I was always returning -1 (then I tries with 1) when the two entries were not equals, and now that I check greater or smaller, it works fine !

And when you think about it, it would be logical for PHP to try to win time this way !